# Powershell, losing custom object attributes in hash table

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a collection of custom objects in powershell and store them in a hashtable. The problem is that the custom attributes disapear when I put the object into a hashtable.

```
$customObject = New-Object object

$customObject | Add-member -membertype noteproperty -name customValue -value "test"

Write-Host $customObject.customValue

$hashTable = @{}

$hashTable.add("custom", $customObject)

$object = $hashTable["custom"]

$object.customValue = 7
```

When I execute this code I get the following output.

```
test
Property 'customValue' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\temp\test2.ps1:15 char:9
+ $object. <<<< customValue = 7
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Is there some way I can use the custom attribute after I've placed it into a collection?

Comment: The code works for me. What PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: I'm using powershell 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using PowerShell 3.0 on 64-bit Windows 7.  In 3.0 your code runs as expected, but in 2.0 (`powershell.exe -Version 2.0`) I get the same error as you.  What's really strange is this output under 2.0:

```
PS> [Object]::ReferenceEquals($customObject, $object)
True
PS> $customObject | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Object

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
customValue NoteProperty System.String customValue=test


PS> $object | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Object

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
```

So, PowerShell agrees that they're the same object, yet only one has a `customValue` property.  I also notice that if I change the way you are adding `$customObject` to `$hashTable` from this...

```
$hashTable.add("custom", $customObject)
```

...to this...

```
$hashTable["custom"] = $customObject
```

...then your code works as expected under PowerShell 2.0.  So, it seems like something is going wrong in the call to `Add()`, and that behavior must have been fixed in 3.0.

Another workaround is to change the first line from this...

```
$customObject = New-Object object
```

...to this...

```
$customObject = New-Object PSObject
```

...and your code runs without error in both versions of PowerShell.  You can then shorten the first two lines to this...

```
$customObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ customValue = "test" }
```

Comment: Works great. I'm running powershell version 2.0